# Netlogo - Behavior Space

Tags: netlogo

I want to run experiments using behavior space. However, the number of experiments needed is depending on the length of a list which is dynamic subject to the external data loaded. Hence , I want to do something like below which is not supported:

[image]

what is the correct way to do so? thanks

Comment: How do you tell your model which external dataset to load when running it without BehaviorSpace?

Comment: there is a data import precedure. I want the behavior space to automatically determine how many runs needed based on the length of a given imported list from the external data source which is dynamically changing everyday. I am going to deploy this model in a remote server for repetitive usage.

Comment: Have you looked at the [user manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#advanced-usage) on running this headlessly? It may make the most sense to get your experiment set up in xml and then have a script to edit the xml parameterization each day to reflect your external data as needed.

Comment: i am using bat or sha file to run it. how to solve my problem about auto adjusting the max number of runs in experiments?

Comment: The best I can think of is to set the range for "run-number" to a value you know will be higher than the `length shift-plan`, then add a stop condition to your experiment with `run-number > length shift-plan`.  It's not ideal, but it might get close to what you want.

Comment: how to implement this "stop condition" in behavior space?

Comment: Behaviorspace has a field called "Stop condition". If you put a line of code in there like `behaviorspace-run-number > length shift-plan` the run will initialize but immediately terminate. So, you will get output for those runs, but they will all be the default variable values. Also, if you are trying to respond to someone, put an '@' symbol in front of their name as they may not check this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You note that you do this with a .bat or .sha file. If that's the case, here's a .bat solution. However, I'm not sure what your data looks like- in this example I just used the number of entries in a csv file to determine the number of runs needed.

So, I have a data file called 'example_data.csv' that looks like this:

```
1
100
1000
10000
```

I have an .nlogo file with an Input widget that defines a `global` variable called `n_runs`. I pulled out the xml for an BehaviorSpace experiment and saved it in a file called "experiment_base.xml"- it looks like:

```
<experiments>
  <experiment name="experiment" repetitions="1" sequentialRunOrder="false" runMetricsEveryStep="false">
    <setup>setup</setup>
    <go>tick</go>
    <timeLimit steps="5"/>
    <metric>count turtles</metric>
    <steppedValueSet variable="n_runs" first="1" step="1" last="1"/>
  </experiment>
</experiments>
```

I have a .bat file that:

- counts the number of entries in my 'example_data.csv"
- reads in the 'experiment_base.xml' file and replaces the `last="1"` with the number read above, then writes this as a new experiment called 'mod_experiments.xml'
- runs the experiment using the newly generated experiments file

This entire bat file looks like:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" example_data.csv | find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a

powershell -Command "(gc experiment_base.xml) -replace '<steppedValueSet variable=\"n_runs\" first=\"1\" step=\"1\" last=\"1\"/>', '<steppedValueSet variable=\"n_runs\" first=\"1\" step=\"1\" last=\"%number%\"/>' | Set-Content mod_experiments.xml

echo "Running experiment..."

netlogo-headless.bat ^
--model dynamic_behaviorspace.nlogo ^
--setup-file mod_experiments.xml ^
--table table-output.csv
```

This outputs results for 4 experiments, since I had 4 values in my data file. If I modify the number of entries in the csv and rerun the .bat file, I get results for a corresponding number of runs.